# Change color text on image hover (the text is in the div under image ex: img > div: p)

Tags: css

I am trying to select the element which is inside a div under an image tag to trigger color change when the image get hovered. 
Can you please point me what has been done wrong or if its even possible to do like that?

```css
img.topic-hover:hover div.post-information ~ p.topic  {
 color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}

img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<img class='topic-hover' src='http://s28.postimg.org/61z157tz1/post1.jpg'>
<div class='post-information'>
  <p class='topic'>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m9wfwceq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miswrite your selector :`img.topic-hover:hover + div.post-information  p.topic` or `img.topic-hover:hover ~ div.post-information  p.topic` would work

```css
img.topic-hover:hover + div.post-information  p.topic  {
 color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}

img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<img class='topic-hover' src='http://s28.postimg.org/61z157tz1/post1.jpg'>
<div class='post-information'>
  <p class='topic'>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: GCyrillus, thank you for the suggestion. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the next selector in CSS(+).

```css
img.topic-hover:hover + div>.topic{   
  color: red;
}

    img {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
     }
```

```html
<img class='topic-hover' src='http://s28.postimg.org/61z157tz1/post1.jpg' />

<div class='post-information'>

  <p class='topic'>Text</p>
  
</div>
```

**Explanation**

You can't include any element inside a element like a img or a input,which need to be written as a self-closed element.

```
<img src="something.jpg" alt="img"/>
/** not like this**/
<img src="something.jpg" alt="img"></img>
```

For this reason, you need to use the next selector.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `~`

```css
img.topic-hover:hover ~ div.post-information p.topic  {
 color: rgb(88, 202, 230);
}

img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<img class='topic-hover' src='http://s28.postimg.org/61z157tz1/post1.jpg'>
<div class='post-information'>
  <p class='topic'>Text</p>
</div>
```